# Uninstalling Lua

Tags: macos, lua, uninstallation

How in the world do I get rid of Lua on my Macbook Air?

I installed the programming language just to test it out and now I am not sure how to get rid of it.

I used the official Lua website <lua.org> to install it and followed the instructions on the download page using 'curl' or whatever it is.

I am a programming beginner. Other languages, like Java and Python, don't have this issue. Can someone please help me get rid of the annoying thing? I don't need it clogging up my computer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacOS, but try going to the Lua source directory (the same one where you invoked `make`) and typing `make uninstall`. Also, there may be another StackExchange that is more appropriate for this question. This question is about OS usage, but StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: I want to thank luther for helping me! Use `sudo make uninstall` because just `make uninstall` will give you an error and tell you permission denied, but I believe I got rid of lua. Once this happened and I attempted to use lua in my terminal by typing 'lua', it said `zsh: command not found: lua` Please let me know if there are other steps I should take if this is not enough.

Comment: @luther - it would be helpful to enter your comment as an answer, because it solved OP's problem. And it will likely help others in the future.

Comment: @jakub: I would, but I'm not sure if this is the right StackExchange for this question.

Comment: @luther: Would you mind if someone else made it into an answer? It was really helpful. I'm sorry if this question was asked in the wrong place. I was unaware of different 'stacks' existing and this was the one I always heard about, so I assumed the question was correct. Lua is cool and all, but I like the freedom and ability to be able to remove and add things to my computer as I please.

Comment: Maybe you guys are right. I can't find an SE for MacOS. I've added my answer.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ is the apple stackexchange, but this question applies to many systems, including macos and linux systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's Makefile has an `uninstall` target which should allow you to remove it from your system. `cd` to the Lua source directory (`lua-5.4.3` for the current version) and type this command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

The `sudo` is required if you need administrative privileges to remove software.

(I'm not familiar with MacOS, but from the comments, it seems to work the same way as it does on GNU systems.)